# iptables NAT configuration

Tags: iptables, nat

Hello I am experiencing some issues with my iptables.
Here's what I want to do:

> A(eth0)--------(eth0)B(eth2)---------------(eth2)C

Brackets are interface names and A, B and C are hosts.
Now I would like to forward port number 80 of host C so that It would be accessed via host A.
host A is 192.168.1.254
host C is 192.168.3.2

I intentionally ACCEPTed all FILTER chain options as the default policy because I wanted to make sure that NAT is working properly first. I enabled ip_forward.

So here's what I have done:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp - d 192.168.1.254 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.2
```

However it is not working. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is how I have done it:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat –p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 –dport 80 -j DNAT –to-destination 192.168.3.2:80
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat –p tcp –d 192.168.3.2 –-dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.3.1
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need NAT at all in this case. You're not using NAT in its most frequent use case of proving network access to a large network from a single public IP. You should simply route the packets with the IP forwarding.

There shouldn't be any reason that NAT would be required for accessing C from A if a) IPv4 forwarding is turned on and b) your IPTables FORWARD chain is set to accept forwarded packets.

But if you insist, I'd suggest using SNAT:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j SNAT --to-source (IP of Host B eth2)
```

Note for future readers: the eth2 reference is for the outgoing interface on the (center) NAT'ing computer when connections are being initiated and refers to the name of the same interface that the source IP is being set to.

Comment: should I add this on top of my rule on my question or just this command by itself?

Comment: It should be used instead of your rule. That said, I really don't think you need NAT at all for routing between RFC1918 networks. It really just isn't necessary. If you're trying SECURE one network from another one while allowing web access, you need the stateful packet inspection aspect of a firewall NOT Network Address Translation.

Comment: Well I know but this is sort of a homework. So I cannot do anything else...

Comment: Be aware that homework questions are off-topic in Serverfault and likely to be closed at any time.